# Is "SharePoint Foundation 2010" free for client

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010

Is SharePoint Foundation 2010 free for sell to any customer. 
I already have physical two servers with following tools:

- Windows Server 2008 (Web Server)
- Sql Server 2008 (Database Server)

I already published couple of ASP.NET website on this server.

Now my question is; can I configure SharePoint Foundation 2010 without any extra cost if I ready have registered Windows Server 2008 and Sql Server 2008? Or do I need to purchase some licenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mohsin

You can configure SharePoint Foundation 2010 without any extra cost. However if you are planning on internet enabling your SharePoint site then you will have to look into "External Connector" licenses for Windows Server. The following post has good information on the External Connector licensing

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010setup/thread/39ac1283-a093-4101-8eb5-194670db3f19